# Shift columns using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have headers like Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, etc. you see where it goes.

Now I have also columns that sum up the quarters but they are more on the right. Now how can I move those columns next to the single month column based on the headers mentioned above?

I started with something like:

```
Sub Insert_Column()

Dim x As Long, rng As Range

Set rng = Range("F2:K2")

For Each cell In rng

    If cell = "Mar" Then
        Columns("M").Cut
        Columns("H").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

M would be the summarizing column in my case and it should be placed besides H BUT of course those columns are not always M or H, the headers are dynamic.

Comment: What is the link between your "M" and "H"? "H" seems to be the column containing "Mar" but "M" seems to depend on information that you have neglected to share.

Comment: Are you actually attempting to `.Insert` a column in the worksheet, or do you just need to adjust where some data is displayed? Either way, it might be easier to to the actual `.Insert` and have Excel move everything for you.

Comment: Hi there. Currently in H the month September is the header and therefore i want to have next to it the column which sums up the quarter (Jul-Sep). This summing column is currently in M.

And No i don't want to insert a column, i want to move columns based on the header of one of the columns i want to have another one (or two next) to it.

Comment: Unless you give some idea of where these "summarizing columns" are and how they are to be identified and mapped to the target columns where they are to be inserted, your question is impossible to answer. Also -- how many quarters of data do you have? In your code you seem to have 6 months (since you are looping over a range of 6 columns) Is it always 6? 12? Does it vary? How is the code supposed to determine such things? It seems that you have an idea of what you want to do, but you haven't sharpened that idea to anything approaching specifications for a sub.

Comment: Hi John.
In columns G-L there are columns with headers of months Aug-Jan but if the actual month changes from Juli to August, there will be Sep-Feb and so on. In columns M-P there are Summarizing columns Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4. Now the challenge is, that I would like to have the summarizing column Q1 right after March, Q2 after June, Q3 after September, Q4 after December. So the code should be searching for "March" from G2-L2 and move the quarterly column next to it. I hope this is a little better explained.. Thanks! :)

Comment: It still is a little vague.  You seem to be suggesting that you have 6 months of monthly data (in columns G-L) but 4 quarters of summary data (in columns M-P). You would like to move the summary data next to the last month in the quarter. Seems easy enough -- but what if the last month in the quarter isn't one of those 6 months? Are you trying to insert 4 columns or 2 columns? Also, you specified the headers for the month columns, but you said nothing about any headers for the sum columns. Are they "Q1", "Q2", etc. ?

Comment: Hi John. You are exactly right. Headers of sum columns = Q1, Q2 etc. if the last month of those 6 isn't one at the end of a quarter i simply don't want to have sum next to it. I just want sums next to "end of the quarter" months.